# Generate random variable in poisson regression being significant

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I am simulating poisson regression data with this code:

```
set.seed(1)
N = 40

pop = round(runif(N,500,5000),0) 
x1 = rnorm(N,1,0.5) 
x2 = rnorm(N,1,0.5) 
x3 <- sample(c(1,2), N, replace = T)
x4 <- sample(c(1,2), N, replace = T)
x5 <- sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), N, replace = T)
x6 <- rnorm(N,1,50)  
beta0 = 0
beta1 = 0.005
beta2 = 0.009
beta3 = 0
beta4 = 1
beta5 = -0.0012

lambda = exp(beta0 + beta1*x1 + beta2*x2 + beta3*x3 + beta4*x3 + beta5*x3*x4 + log(pop)) 
y = rpois(N,lambda)
x3 <- as.factor(x3)
x4 <- as.factor(x4)
x5 <- as.factor(x5)

m = glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3*x4 + x5 + x6, family="poisson",offset=log(pop)) 
summary(m)
```

And I get this,

```
Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 * x4 + x5 + x6, family = "poisson", 
    offset = log(pop))

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.74321  -0.73937   0.06889   0.53340   1.84607  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  9.956e-01  5.956e-03 167.141  < 2e-16 ***
x1           5.543e-03  3.575e-03   1.551  0.12102    
x2           1.118e-02  3.494e-03   3.199  0.00138 ** 
x32          9.967e-01  4.158e-03 239.689  < 2e-16 ***
x42         -6.077e-03  5.853e-03  -1.038  0.29917    
x5B         -1.202e-04  4.720e-03  -0.025  0.97969    
x5C          3.099e-03  5.249e-03   0.590  0.55489    
x5D          4.946e-04  6.402e-03   0.077  0.93842    
x5E          1.095e-02  4.196e-03   2.610  0.00906 ** 
x6           6.433e-06  3.566e-05   0.180  0.85687    
x32:x42     -4.604e-03  7.905e-03  -0.582  0.56027    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 127081.497  on 39  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:     36.646  on 29  degrees of freedom
AIC: 504.31

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

How is it possible that I have X5E significant if it is not when I simulate the lambdas.

Best

Comment: You should explain what the code is trying to do, (simulate Poisson regression but with X5 not in the true model): 1) We shouldn't have to infer what you're trying to do from your code; it conflates potential problems what you're attempting with your ability to correctly code it. Your code looks fine but being able to follow the code shouldn't be a hurdle to readers understanding the setup.  2) Not everyone knows R, but the issue you're asking about would be useful to anyone performing a simulation in whatever other language. ...

Answer (score 2):

An answer that deliberately takes a (slightly) Socratic approach.

1. Given the set up you have (i.e. with H0 true), what proportion of the times that you generate data this way (with different seeds!) should you expect to see with $p<\alpha$ on the coefficient?
2. If you try many such seeds, what proportion of incorrect rejections do you see in practice?

·͏ [3. If you were to do this experiment an extremely large number of times, can you explain why the two answers might nevertheless differ a little bit? I am not suggesting you try enough times to show that it happens (however I have just done so, since I wanted to see how large this effect might be in this case).]